# How to disable JSESSIONID cookie-based (and any else) session-tracking features in jetty 9?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, jetty

i wish to disable all kinds of session tracking features in Jetty 9 for my stateless- or manually maintained state Spring MVC application, but i failed to find any working examples showing how to do so.

I have tried the following `/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml` tag:

```
...
<security:http use-expressions="true"
               disable-url-rewriting="true"
               create-session="stateless">
...
```

Alongside with the following `/WEB-INF/jetty-web.xml` descriptor in war:

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd">

<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <Get name="sessionHandler">
        <Get name="sessionManager">
            <Set name="usingCookies" type="boolean">false</Set>
        </Get>
    </Get>
</Configure>
```

But i am still getting JSESSIONID cookies whenever trying to open any page of my application. Any hints why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With servlet 3 it is possible to set session tracking mode as a part of servlet registration - [`ServletContext#setSessionTrackingModes`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#setSessionTrackingModes%28java.util.Set%29)... you can try that.

However in your case I would investigate who is calling `HttpServletRequest#getSession(...)`. Put breakpoint in this method to see who is calling it. Some piece of code in your application is initializing session.

Comment: `SessionTrackingModes` only allows you to choose between URL, SSL and COOKIE versions of tracking, it is impossible to disable them completly via this way. Isn't in Jetty 9 anything like Tomcat 7's `/META-INF/context.xml` file with contents of `<Context disableURLRewriting="true" cookies="false" />` effectively disabling both URL and COOKIE trackers of session disregarding whether was getSession() called or not?

Comment: That would mean all calls to `getSession()` should end up with error. This is not covered by Servlet API and I am not aware of such configuration in Tomcat (not so familiar with Jetty). However you can implement your own servlet Filter and wrap incomming requests with `HttpServletRequestWrapper` and do this yourself. But in the end you will need to face the places where `getSession()` is called and get rid of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish the same goal by invalidating the session as soon as the request is complete.  You can do that with a `ServletRequestListener` like this:

```
public class SessionKiller implements ServletRequestListener {

    public void requestInitialized(ServletRequestEvent sre) {
        // no-op
    }

    public void requestDestroyed(ServletRequestEvent sre) {
        final HttpServletRequest servletRequest = (HttpServletRequest)sre.getServletRequest();
        final HttpSession session = servletRequest.getSession(false);
        if (session != null) {
            session.invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

To use the `ServletRequestListener`, add the following to the `web-app` element in the webapp's`web.xml`:

```
<listener>
  <listener-class>YOUR-PACKAGE-NAME.SessionKiller</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to invalidating created sessions as suggested by user100464, I used a [HttpSessionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html) that throws Exceptions whenever someone tries to open a session, e.g. by calling `request.getSession()`, and removed occurences.

```
public class PreventSessions implements HttpSessionListener {

    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("sessions are not allowed");
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("sessions are not allowed");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Implementation of what [Pavel Horal suggested in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17262207/365237), using Spring Boot, is simply this:

```
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import java.util.Collections;

@Configuration
public class WebContainerConfiguration {
  @Bean
  public ServletContextInitializer servletContextInitializer() {
    return servletContext -> servletContext.setSessionTrackingModes(Collections.emptySet());
  }
}
```

working nicely for me. Thank you!

Comment: If you're in Spring Boot you also have the option to just do this with configuration in `application.properties` add the line: `server.servlet.session.tracking-modes=`